# Java design strucutre

Tags: java, oop

If I want to write bunch of sort classes (insertion, merge, etc) with void `sort()` method common in all of them, then I was hoping to have an interface or abstract class that these classes can implement or extend from.

However, if I plan on using the sort method as static and can not keep static method in abstract super class.

What would be proper way for such implementation?

Comment: Don't make it static!

Comment: You have two contradictory desires. Static and polymorphic. It's one or the other.

Comment: OK, more seriously: you will need a `sorter` object.  This object isn't the array you're sorting, but an object whose purpose is to provide the sort algorithm. The sort method will be an instance method of that object.

Comment: Is there a reason WHY you want to make it static? If you really want to make the methods static, it might be best to make them all static methods of the same class, e. g.  `Sorter.insertionSort(myArray)`, `Sorter.mergeSort(myArray)` etc.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think you are trying to make it complicated. Your problem is straight forward. You just need to code few sort functions. You can't try to apply object oriented thinking on everywhere. This is just implementation of different reusable algorithms. If you really need to DESIGN this. You can try this way:

```
interface Sorter<T> {

    // This method accepts any type of object and sorts it and return it in sorted order
    //Used Generics to support all types. You can read T as List or Array if you want to understand it in a simple way
    public T sort(T t);
}



class MergeSort implements Sorter<int[]> {


    @Override
    public int[] sort(int[] numbersToSort) {
    //algorithm goes here

    }

}


class BubbleSort implements Sorter<int[]> {

    @Override
    public int[] sort(int[] numbersToSort) {
        //algorithm goes here   
    }

}


class InsertionSort implements Sorter<int[]> {

    @Override
    public int[] sort(int[] numbersToSort) {
        //algorithm goes here
    }

}





enum SortingAlgorithms{
INSERTIONSORT,
BUBBLESORT,
MERGESORT;

}

class SorterFactory {
    public static Sorter<int[]> getSortingAlgorithm(SortingAlgorithms alg) {
        switch(alg) {
        case INSERTIONSORT : 
            return new InsertionSort();

        case BUBBLESORT :
            return new BubbleSort();

        case MERGESORT :
            return new MergeSort(); 

        default:
            return new BubbleSort();
        }
    }
}



public class SortingExecutor {
    public static void main (String... cmdArgs) {

        int[] toBeSorted = {6, 7, 1, 0, 3};

        //get a bubble sort algorith which can take int[] as input and return the sorted int[] as output
        Sorter<int[]> bubbleSort = SorterFactory.getSortingAlgorithm(SortingAlgorithms.BUBBLESORT);
        bubbleSort.sort(toBeSorted);



    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A Bridge design pattern will help you here. One hierarchy contains different aggregates to hold the data with *sorter reference* in base Aggregate class. Another hierarchy with *Sorter* as a base class provides different kinds of sorting algorithms in concrete classes.

The advantage will be both the aspects can grow independently.

Only variation from Bridge pattern will be that Aggregate-Sorter relationship will be bidirectional (Little bit similar to Iterator)

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understood your question a solution to use a `static` method `sort(int data [ ])` can be done using Stategy pattern (I used int data to ease comprenhension).
[image]
As you said, group all your sort strategies as for example, `InsertionSort`,`MergeSort`, `Quicksort` etc... in an interface `SortAlgorithm` implement the abstract method `sort(int data [])`.
Then write a class `Sorter` that owns a reference to the abstract type `SortAlgorithm` that use  `final sort(int data [ ], int choice)`where `choice` in my example is an integer given by the client

```
class Client{
   public static void main(String [ ] args){
      Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
      int choice = sc.nextInt();
      int data= new int [5]
      data={3,7,7,1,0};
      Sorter.sort(data,choice);
   }
```